# jQuery: Smoke over image that resizes

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I want to add smoke over an image (that automaticly resizes to the users screen width), is there anyway of doing this using jQuery, CSS and HTML? Thank you very much. How would I integrate it into this code (I know it is sloppy). And I would rather not use any external files... Thanks for the help.

```
This is my HTML:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #myCanvas{
    background:black;
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: .5;
}
img{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
 </style>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
// Create an array to store our particles
var particles = [];

// The amount of particles to render
var particleCount = 160;

// The maximum velocity in each direction
var maxVelocity = 2;

// The target frames per second (how often do we want to update / redraw the scene)
var targetFPS = 33;

// Set the dimensions of the canvas as variables so they can be used.
var canvasWidth = 1366;
var canvasHeight = 768;

// Create an image object (only need one instance)
var imageObj = new Image();

// Once the image has been downloaded then set the image on all of the particles
imageObj.onload = function() {
    particles.forEach(function(particle) {
            particle.setImage(imageObj);
    });
};

// Once the callback is arranged then set the source of the image
imageObj.src = "http://www.blog.jonnycornwell.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Smoke10.png";

// A function to create a particle object.
function Particle(context) {

    // Set the initial x and y positions
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;

    // Set the initial velocity
    this.xVelocity = 0;
    this.yVelocity = 0;

    // Set the radius
    this.radius = 5;

    // Store the context which will be used to draw the particle
    this.context = context;

    // The function to draw the particle on the canvas.
    this.draw = function() {

        // If an image is set draw it
        if(this.image){
            this.context.drawImage(this.image, this.x-128, this.y-128);         
            // If the image is being rendered do not draw the circle so break out of the draw function                
            return;
        }
        // Draw the circle as before, with the addition of using the position and the radius from this object.
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        this.context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)";
        this.context.fill();
        this.context.closePath();
    };

    // Update the particle.
    this.update = function() {
        // Update the position of the particle with the addition of the velocity.
        this.x += this.xVelocity;
        this.y += this.yVelocity;

        // Check if has crossed the right edge
        if (this.x >= canvasWidth) {
            this.xVelocity = -this.xVelocity;
            this.x = canvasWidth;
        }
        // Check if has crossed the left edge
        else if (this.x <= 0) {
            this.xVelocity = -this.xVelocity;
            this.x = 0;
        }

        // Check if has crossed the bottom edge
        if (this.y >= canvasHeight) {
            this.yVelocity = -this.yVelocity;
            this.y = canvasHeight;
        }

        // Check if has crossed the top edge
        else if (this.y <= 0) {
            this.yVelocity = -this.yVelocity;
            this.y = 0;
        }
    };

    // A function to set the position of the particle.
    this.setPosition = function(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };

    // Function to set the velocity.
    this.setVelocity = function(x, y) {
        this.xVelocity = x;
        this.yVelocity = y;
    };

    this.setImage = function(image){
        this.image = image;
    }
}

// A function to generate a random number between 2 values
function generateRandom(min, max){
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

// The canvas context if it is defined.
var context;

// Initialise the scene and set the context if possible
function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {

        // Set the context variable so it can be re-used
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // Create the particles and set their initial positions and velocities
        for(var i=0; i < particleCount; ++i){
            var particle = new Particle(context);

            // Set the position to be inside the canvas bounds
            particle.setPosition(generateRandom(0, canvasWidth), generateRandom(0, canvasHeight));

            // Set the initial velocity to be either random and either negative or positive
            particle.setVelocity(generateRandom(-maxVelocity, maxVelocity), generateRandom(-maxVelocity, maxVelocity));
            particles.push(particle);            
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Please use a modern browser");
    }
}

// The function to draw the scene
function draw() {
    // Clear the drawing surface and fill it with a black background
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 1366, 768);

    // Go through all of the particles and draw them.
    particles.forEach(function(particle) {
        particle.draw();
    });
}

// Update the scene
function update() {
    particles.forEach(function(particle) {
        particle.update();
    });
}

// Initialize the scene
init();

// If the context is set then we can draw the scene (if not then the browser does not support canvas)
if (context) {
    setInterval(function() {
        // Update the scene befoe drawing
        update();

        // Draw the scene
        draw();
    }, 1000 / targetFPS);
}
});//]]>  

</script>









<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body class='  wsite-theme-light'>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="bg-wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="sitename" class="sitetitle">ZOMBIEZ, A UNIQUE GAMEMODE</div>
        </div>
                    <div id="startcontainer">
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/smoke_effect.js"></script>
                            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                            <script src="/files/theme/smoke_effect.js"></script>
                            <img id="mainscreenimage" src="http://gamershavennews.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/gm_construct0003.jpeg" alt="" />
                            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1366" height="768"></canvas>
                            <div id="DIV_1">
                                <a href="#content" id="A_2"></a>
                            </div>

                    </div>
        <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="content">
        <div id="intro">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        (function() {
                        var img = document.getElementById('startcontainer').firstChild;
                        var height = $(window).height(); 
                            img.onload = function() {
                                if(img.height > img.width) {
                                    //img.height = '100%';
                                    img.height = height;
                                    img.width = 'auto';
                                }
                            };
                        }());
                    </script>
            </div>




            {content}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footer-content">{footer}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style='display:none'>{title}</div>
<div style='display:none'>{menu}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anything you have tried till now?

Comment: I tried using this fiddle, but it didn't work.. http://jsfiddle.net/jonnyc/Ujz4P/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `max-width: 100%` to resize your images

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ujz4P/1775/)

CSS

```
#myCanvas{
    background:black;
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: .5;
}

img{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I posted my code, do u have any idea how I would need to integrate that so the smoke is over the http://gamershavennews.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/gm_construct0003.jpeg image?

Comment: I thought it was working, but it isn't for some reason, I updated mu code.. I don't know why it doesn't work, I almost did exactly the same as in the fiddle.

Comment: @Jordi - http://jsbin.com/sufewonu/1/edit - You have to put the jQuery library in the `<head>` tag... also before you calling your script. This is very basic.

Answer (score 2):

Change max width to 100%

ie

```
 max-width: 100%;
```